# При копировании файла создается папка

Tags: php

Есть массив с адресами и названием файлов

```
Array ( 
  [0] => /uploads/2017/04/provoloka.jpg
  [1] => /uploads/2017/02/provoloka-vyazalnaya.jpg
)
```

Нужно скопировать все файлы в папк `1`, чтобы файлы имели вид

```
/1/uploads/2017/04/provoloka.jpg
```

Мой код

```
foreach ($value as $v) {//Перебираем массив
  $v=substr($v,1);//Убираем первый знак - /
  if (file_exists($v)) {//Проверяем существует ли фаил
    if(!file_exists('1/'.$v)) {//Проверяем скопирован ли файл
      //$t= explode('/', $v);//Из адреса делаем массив, чтобы убрать название файла
      //$s = [];//Создаем пустой массив
      //for($i=0; $i<count($t)-1; $i++) {//Перебираем массив с адресом файла
      //  $s[] = $t[$i];//Заносим все в массив
      //}
      //$d = implode('/',$s);//Получаем адрес к файлу без названия файла
      $d = dirname($v);
      if (file_exists($d)) {//Проверяем существует ли папка куда будем копировать
        copy($v, '1/'.$v);//Если есть то копируем файл
      } else {
        mkdir('1/'.$d, 0777, true);//Если папки нет, то создаем ее
        copy($v, '1/'.$v);// И копируем в нее файл
      }
    }
  } else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема заключается в том, что он вместо файла создает папку

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: на картинке я вижу лишь иконку папки. вот если бы у вас в строке адреса было это имя файлов, то другой вопрос.

Comment: @teran Подправил вопрос, так?

Comment: а вы знаете о существовании всяких там функций, вроде `dirname` ?

Comment: что-то ощущение, что у вас ранее было `mkdir("1/$v", ...)` затем вы исправили на `$d`, а файлы остались.

Comment: либо изначально было `< count($t)`, а потом добавили еще `-1`. это к вопросу о том, что `dirname` исключил был такие проблемы, сократив код.

Comment: @teran теперь знаю, о `dirname `. Копируя код в вопрос указал `-1`, а в самом скрипте нет, после замена на `dirname ` все заработало, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если директория создана, значит такой путь был передан в аргументе функции. Судя по вашему коду, возможны были два варианта. Первый - опечатка в `mkdir("1/$v")` вместо `$d`, вторая - цикл `< count($t)`, вместо `< count($t) - 1`, таким образом само имя файла тоже попадало в имя папки.

*как мы уже выяснили проблема была в -1*

Тем не менее, для решения задач старайтесь использовать подходящие инструменты. Например, не стоит разбирать пути самостоятельно, для этого есть соответствующие функции.  Не стоит также и писать множество вложенных условий и т.п. Возможно лучше  просто в несколько приемов подготовить данные, и потом также просто их обработать.  Также постоянное конкатенация и вычисление пути повышает риск опечаток и снижает понятность и читаемость кода (не  говоря уже о том, что при смене пути придется править каждую строку), а код должен быть прост как валенок, чем проще, тем лучше.

Вот пример кода (возможно с опечатками), в котором эти проблемы не так актуальны:

```
$files = [
          "/uploads/2017/04/provoloka.jpg",
          "/uploads/2017/02/provoloka-vyazalnaya.jpg"
        ];


// из какой директрию и в какую копируем
$sourceDir = dirname(__FILE__);
$targetDir = $sourceDir."1" ;

// пути для файлов
$data = array_map(function($f) use ($sourceDir, $targetDir){
                     return [
                        'from' => $sourceDir.$f,
                        'to'   => $targetDir.$f,
                    ];
                }, $files);

// фильтруем только то, что действительно следует копировать
$data = array_filter($data, function($c){
                    return file_exists($c['from']) 
                           && !file_exists($c['to']);
            });


// работаем с файлами
foreach($data as $c){
    $d = dirname($c['to']);

    if(!file_exists($d)){
        mkdir($d, 777, true);
    }

    copy($c['from'], $c['to']);
}
```

для  особых эстетов, можно сделать `$data = array_column($data, 'to', 'from')` и цикл вида `foreach($data as $from => $to){ ... }`

Comment: Вот сколько кода надо написать на PHP вместо `cp -R uploads 1`.

Comment: @TotalPusher очевидно, ваша команда скопирует все что есть, при этом заменяет существующие файлы. Здесь же предполагается, что список файлов получен из БД с проверкой их фактического наличия + копируются только те, что еще не были скопированы.

Comment: Может быть. Тогда `cp -nR uploads 1`. А файлы ТС может получил через `glob()`. Ладно, это риторический вопрос.